# brcmsmac does not work

Tags: linux, drivers, wifi, gnu, broadcom

I am attempting to enable my wireless interface in **Slax Linux**, so far, I know the driver I need is `brcmsmac`, since I have a broadcom card; and this work in **Slackware**.

The driver is available and does not show any errors when I load it with:

```
# modprobe brcmsmac
```

But no new interface is loaded.

Here is I've tried:

```
# lspci | grep Network

03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)

# ifconfig -a

eth0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e8:11:32:5f:ff:5e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 41  base 0xc000  

lo: flags=8<LOOPBACK>  mtu 16436
        loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Any suggestions?

I am sorry @slm, here's dmesg output

```
# dmesg | grep brcmsmac

brcmsmac bcma0:0: mfg 4bf core 812 rev 24 class 0 irq 16
ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: fail to load firmware brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw
ieee80211 phy0: brcmsmac: Failed to find firmware usually in /lib/firmware/brcm
brcmsmac: brcms_bcma_probe: brcms_attach failed!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the output from `dmesg` I would suggest downloading the firmware from the [broadcom site](http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/brcm80211). Check out that link, there are pretty detailed instructions on how to download and install the firmware that the `dmesg` error message is mentioning.

#### general steps

**1.** download firmware file: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

**2.** copy `brcm/bcm43xx-0.fw` and `brcm/bcm43xx_hdr-0.fw` to `/lib/firmware/brcm`

**3.** Use the nvram file installed in your system and copy it to `/lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac-sdio.txt` The firmware can be found in the linux-firmware repository.

**NOTE:**

```
For 4329: cp brcm/brcmfmac4329.bin /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac-sdio.bin
For 4330: cp brcm/brcmfmac4330.bin /lib/firmware/brcm/brcmfmac-sdio.bin
```

**4.** Run modprobe brcmsmac (or something like that)

I may be missing steps but it will be something along those lines. Again consult the broadcom link I mentioned above for further details.